# CSV Export shows HTML elements in the downloaded CSV File

Tags: php, html, csv, yii, cgridview

I am using CGRIDVIEW ... I hav fixed the column size to fixed width(for that I am using  tag in the 'value' key of array ) .. now I want to export this Grid Results into a CSV file ... Its fine with the Exporting option ... but the problem is I get  tags written into the CSV file ... How do i tackle this problem ?

View is =>

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
            'type' => 'bordered striped',
            'id' => 'bike_search',   
            'dataProvider' => $model->search_bike(),
            'ajaxUpdate' => true,
            'filter' => null, 
            'template'=>'<div style="overflow:auto;">{items}</div>{pager}{summary}',
            'columns' => $selected_columns,
            'enablePagination' => true
        ));
```

Model Is ->

```
$selected_columns[] = array(
                'header' => 'Name',
                'name' => 'bike_name',
                'type'=>'html',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'word-wrap: break-word;'),
                'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center;'),
                'value'=> '"<div style=\"width:100px;\">" . $data["bike_name"]. "</div>"', 

            );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to set content type="text/csv" on your csv exporting functionality
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the solution ...

In the Controller function to export CSV .. I added strip_tags() to the returning data array

```
fputcsv(filename, strip_tags($data));
```

And Problem solved!